# Android Studio file not found Exception using BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to load an image to an imageView using

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Fotos/i0.png");

```
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Running with the AVE, those lines results in a Exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Fotos/i0.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I've tried several locations to put the file:
app\src\main\Fotos\
app\src\main\res\Fotos\

even 
app\src\main\assets\Fotos\

I'd like not to use assets\drawable once I have to load 1 image from a folder that has 700 files.

Answer (score 0):

First, resources and assets are not files on the Android device. You do not use `decodeFile()`, or any sort of file I/O, to access them.

Second, you cannot invent random new directories in your project tree (e.g., `app\src\main\Fotos`, `app\src\main\res\Fotos\`) and expect that they will be packaged into your APK, let alone be available on the device.

Your primary choices are:

- Put them as drawable resources (e.g., `app/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/`), then use `R` constants to put them into your `ImageView` (e.g., `R.drawable.foo`)
- Put them as assets (`app/src/main/assets/Fotos/`), then use `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on the asset, then use `BitmapFactory` and `decodeStream()` to load in the image